# What is the type of QML this in C++?

Tags: c++, qml

I want to pass the QML item reference to C++. It works using the id explicitly:

```
Item {
  id: qmlitem
  x: CppObj.getValue(qmlitem)
}

// c++
int getValue(QObject * qmlItem) {
  return 0;
}
```

if I pass this:

```
Item {
  x: CppObj.getValue(this)
}
```

QObject * qmlItem is 0x0.

If I replace

```
int getValue(QObject * qmlItem)
```

by

```
int getValue(void * qmlItem)
```

qmlItem is not 0x0 - it has a value but of which type?  Is it possible to obtain the QObject* from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QML, the value of `this` is [currently undefined](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html#javascript-environment-restrictions). Passing it to C++ will not yield any meaningful result. Whatever its content may be, it is not a reference to the current QML item. So just stick to your first solution and pass an ID.